# Sublime Text 2-3 Code Formatting

Tags: html, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

am working in ST3/2 and have tried a couple different formatting tools. In general the formatting is great but I'd like one more preference:
Currently here is how code is formatted

```
    <h4><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"> Who is it For</h4>
```

I'd like to change it to:

```
<h4>
 <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"> 
 Who is it For
</h4>
```

In other words, tags on one line, content on another.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read here for some ideas:
http://sublimetexttips.com/formatting-html-with-sublime-text/

To not get told things you already know you will probably need to tell us the tools you have already tried that don't work the way you want so we know not to recommend this again.